# Why can't I click on things (software-related issue)?

Tags: mouse, package-management

After installing both Gmameui and the Sugar desktop session package I was not able to click on anything inside applications. I can close, minimize, and maximize windows and use the panel and desktop icons but the rest of the system is unusable. I have not deleted the partition in which this system is installed on, but have re-installed Ubuntu in a new partition, so if anyone can help me with this, it would still be of use to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Sugar, found the answer at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465033)

> You don't need to delete the whole
>   .gconf folder, edit the file
>
> ```
> .gconf/apps/metacity/general/%gconf.xml
> ```
>
> delete the tag with name
>   "mouse_button_modifier", in my case
>   this 3 lines:
>
> ```
> <entry name="mouse_button_modifier"
> ```
>
> mtime="1279125807" type="string">
>           disabled
>
> and that's it.

Worked like a charm.  Thanks, moiesk.